# Perform a task every day even if running only in background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I need my application to perform a background task every day, but it does not comply with [Apple's specification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) for running in background.

It's none of these: audio, location, VOIP, news stand, external-accessory—, Bluetooth-central.

I'm planning to use local notifications, but the point is, that if the user doesn't open the app (and just leaves it in the background), I cannot plan new local notifications.

What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Make something else.

Seriously, if your app doesn’t at least technically fit one of those categories, you’re not going to be able to get it to do background work in a way that’ll get you approved for the App Store.

I’ve seen apps that added specific functionality in one of those categories, orthogonal to their actual purpose, to be allowed to run in the background; for instance, there’s a couple of weather apps out there that play a continuous audio file—one of the available sounds being a silent one—in order to be able to update the lock screen’s “now playing” image with live data. If you don’t mind your users being unable to listen to any other music, and have your app continuously active (which might cause additional battery drain), that could work. But if you’re trying to have your app invisibly do things in the background, without interfering with anything else, in a way that’ll get you into the App Store, you’re probably out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Four options:

- Go for jailbreak
- Try to get in the app store as one of those types of apps, making up a feature that uses one of those types.
- (my favorite) Really rethink your system, is it really necessary to schedule background tasks? Can't the user wait a bit when he opens the app? That loading can be performed in background. And can't you offload some of the work to a webserver? Are you collecting data? You shoudln't without the user consent.
- Let your user know that it's important for him (he's the one using it right?) that he opens the app once a day.

I think I covered all yohr options except the one already covered by Noah.